# stopping turtles in the imported drawing to fill the drawing

Tags: netlogo

Actually, I am using patch-ahead 1 condition for stopping my turtles in drawing imported by using "`import-pcolors`" command.

drawing or shape (such as star-fish) is aligned on the center of the world's patches and 4 turtles(seeds) are placed near the center of the origin within shape drawing remained stationary until the end, all other turtles are placed randomly and also moves randomly in the world with `stationary? = false`.

The goal is to completely fill the shape(drawing) without leaving any patch empty in the drawing, by moving the turtles randomly and stop when approaches to next stationary turtle and become `stationary? = true`, and reference for all other remaining non-stationary turtles.

here is what I have tried so far,

```
    to setup
      import-pcolors "starnew.png" ; image imported in the world on patches for turtles to interact

      create-robots num-of-robots
        [
          set seed? false
          set stationary? false
        set shape "circle 2"  
        setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
      ]

      ask turtles
      [
        if who = 0 ; similarly for who = 1 (setxy = 0 1 ), who = 2 (setxy = 1 0 ), who = 3 (setxy = 0 -1 ),  having loaction near centre origin 
        [
          setxy  0 0
          set seed? true
          set stationary? true
          set localized? true
          ]
      ]   
    end
    to go
ask robots with [stationary? != true]
  [

    ifelse pcolor = white   ;; out-shape
      [
        wall
        fd 0.1
        rt random 30
        lt random 30
      ]
      [                     ;; In-shape
        set pos-inside? true
        ifelse ( not any? (robots-on patch-ahead 1 ) with [stationary? = true or seed? = true]   )
        [
          fd 0.1
          rt random 30
          lt random 30
        ]
        [
          set pos-inside? true
          set stationary? true
          set localized? true
          stop
        ]
      ]
  ]
  end
```

the desired behavior I want to achieve is shown in the picture below.
[image]

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What isn't right yet  about your code so far? Is there an error message, incorrect behavior, or what?